# jQuery .on deligation to non-event based functions

Tags: jquery

Not really sure if this is possible but I figured I would shot it out to the community. I have function that is setup using .on and a .promise() to handle a small non-event based function:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(){
   -- click code --
}).promise().done(function(){
   -- Non-Event based function --
});
```

When anchors are added using ajax they receive click event but the promise function is not preformed. Any Thought?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? `.promise()` returns a promise that is fulfilled when all animations on the targets (`document`, in your case) are finished.

Comment: I don't think promise has a purpose in this context, what is it supposed to represent?

Comment: Im trying to figure out a way to execute a function of code that is not part of the click event, but still needs to run when new 'a' are added via ajax.

Comment: You cannot reliably detect new element insertion using any events, and there is no reason to believe that binding to a click event will somehow cause _any_ code to be invoked when a new element is inserted via AJAX. Your only option is setting up a timer and periodically checking if the set of elements that match your selector changes.

Comment: @lanzz, Thank you for your response. Over the course of the day I continued to research this issue and found the same.